# reference the component using the xaml file

Tags: wpf, mvvm, f#

I would like to act on the View from my ViewModelClass by code, not just modifying the properties, to which the XAML binds to.

```ml
member x.SelectedUdl 
  with get() = selectedudl
  and set value = selectedudl  <- value
                  //do fancy things like 
                  //this.Quotes12.ItemsSource <- asyncquotes.gethisto (undls |> Seq.head, 2012)
```

However to do this, I need a reference to the component itself.
Do I have any way to  add a reference to "this" from the xaml or other way ?

```xml
   <UserControl.DataContext>
      <ViewModel:QuotesViewModel>
           <x:Arguments>
              THIS
           </x:Arguments>
      </ViewModel:QuotesViewModel>
   </UserControl.DataContext>
   <DockPanel>
```

```ml
type QuotesViewModel(this:Window) =
    inherit ViewModelBase()
```

**Edit**

I finally added a Global.fs file, in the first position so that it is acessible for all compilation units

```ml
module Global

open FSharpx

type MainWindow = XAML<"MainWindow.xaml">

type Singleton private () =
   static let instance = Singleton()
   let mutable ivalue : MainWindow = null

   static member Instance = instance
   member this.Value 
      with get () = ivalue  
      and set value = ivalue  <- value

let window () =  Singleton.Instance.Value
```

Note that it uses the XAML type provider, so you have to move the FMVVM template MainWindow's Frame up a level to benefit from strong type access.

Then in the View, you can add

```ml
Global.window().TextBox.Text <- "hello"
```

With this, we can use both the declarative way, or the code approach, in a strongly typed way.

Initialisation is easily done

```ml
let mainWindow = MainWindow()
Global.Singleton.Instance.Value <- mainWindow

// Application Entry point
[<STAThread>]
[<EntryPoint>]
let main(_) =(new Application()).Run(mainWindow.Root)
```

(recommendations welcome, I am just starting to look at wpf..)

Comment: I don't really understand your question. First, what kind of stuff are you trying to do exactly? "act on the View" seems vague to me. Also, you don't "act on the View" from the ViewModel in MVVM, you just set up links between them

Comment: I am trying to add to the visual tree n elements.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items.aspx like this

Comment: Where exactly in the View? In a `ListBox`? a `DataGrid`? a `ItemsControl` ?

Comment: Potentially wherever, that is why I would like to get a hold on the entire component.

Comment: Okay, I don't know F# at all but did I just read here that you are giving a Window in parameter of a ViewModel?

Comment: I'm a bit late on this, but calling your View form your Viewmodel and vice versa is the absolute opposite of what you should do in MVVM. You should consider taking a bit more time getting to know the design pattern itself

Comment: I will. I guess there are 2 ideas in the pattern. one is to keep all 'view stuff' in one place separate of the 'pure' model. Another is to keep it as declarative as possible. touching the view from the view model satisfies the 1st idea, but definitely not he 2nd.  However, there are stuff I cant seem to get out of wpf, that I only know to do by code..